# How to find prolog with idapython in non-disassambled function raw bytes?

Tags: idapython

I tried googling but I didn't find much info. I am trying to get the function prolog from an instruction inside a function. The function is in raw bytes. Is this possible to get?

Comment: Could give some context with your question, at least, an example or what you have tried so far ?

Comment: the context is, i am trying to make a analizer finding some xrefs in raw bytes in specific arch armeabi-v7a, after i found this xref to x address, it must happend probably inside a procedure, notice that the access to the xref happend inside that procedure in between a function prolog and epilog, from that, is it posible to go backward to find some kind of sing of function entry/prolog?